# How do you create a list collection in NHibernate with a non-nullable index?

Tags: nhibernate, list, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using FluentNHibernate to map a bi-directional one-to-many relationship where ordering is important, so I'm using a list:

```
        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .AsList(index => index.Column("CHILD_INDEX"))
            .KeyColumn("PARENT_ID")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

On the other side, it's mapped like this:

```
        References(x => x.Parent)
            .Column("PARENT_ID")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Fetch.Join()
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

Now in my actual database, the CHILD_INDEX column is *not nullable*.  However, when NHibernate persists the child elements during an insert, it doesn't insert the CHILD_INDEX column.  It then performs an UPDATE to set the CHILD_INDEX.  This is odd to me, as it certainly has the index value when it does the insert.

Is there a way to tell NHibernate to write the index column during the insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bidirectional indexed collections (i.e. lists and dictionaries) are [not supported](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional).

Since they are *required* to avoid inserting null and then updating (see the note in 6.4. [One-To-Many Associations](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany)), the workaround is to use a bag instead of a list and create a regular index property in the many side.

You can then wrap the collection manipulation to deal with both sides' references and indexes.

Comment: I guess you're right.  But doing it this way, it works (it inserts the PARENT_ID on the child even without inverse specified on the parent).  It then does what I consider to be a superfluous update of the child's index property.  I find the whole thing rather confusing.  Why even have `list` semantics?

Comment: What kind of help is wrapping the collection manipulation if you have to expose the Index property for that, meaning it can be changed by other code arbitrarily later on...

Answer (score 0):

I may not entirely understand your issue, but make sure you set the parent instance on the child model (`x.Parent`) when adding the child to the parent's child collection.

Comment: Yes, it's being set, and the PARENT_ID is being persisted during the insert of the child entity.

Comment: Sorry, misread this as the parent id of the child, not the index of the child.

Comment: However, I have had issues in the past using indexed collections in bi-directional scenarios. You may want to play with using a Bag.

Comment: @CaptainTom - a Bag doesn't give me ordering.  This all works if I make the CHILD_INDEX column nullable.  I would just rather make it NOT NULL, and there doesn't seem to be any reason why it couldn't be included in the insert.

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't have to change the index. You could order after the collection is retrieved, but that is certainly not ideal. Not sure if marking your child side as inverse=true would help in this scenario as I would expect it to affect the parent FK, not the child index.